# Foreign Keys cascading in JPA or database Schema

Tags: sql, database, hibernate, jpa, database-design

I have a separate script that creates the database and tables for each database that we are supporting. I am using JPA to manipulate the data in the database, but JPA does not create the database or the tables.

I want to add a foreign key to a new table with a cascade property so that when a row is deleted in the parent table, the corresponding rows in the child table are also deleted.

I am aware of the annotations necessary to do this in JPA, however I can create the foreign keys and the cascade statements in the script I am using to create the databases.

My question is, since I am using a separate script to create the database tables, can I just add the foreign key / cascade statements in the script and then ignore all of the JPA relationship annotations? Is there advantages/disadvantages to adding this information in both the database script as well as in the JPA code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always have a 2 level check. if you do not use the features of JPA, then it's a big waste of the functionality JPA provides. you should actually make sure that you JPA relations match your DB relations as closely as possible. It will help you a lot as JPA can cache data and even prevent unnecessary calls to DB. 
eg if u have a not null constraint and you persist with no JPA constraint, your DB has to do all the work and throw the exception back.
normally in an application, the network and DB are the slowest factors in the app. so you should try mimicking the constraints in JPA to avoid unnecessary overhead.
also using such constraints you can form bidirectional relationships and have collections of associated entities and many more such advantages.